# Workaround with deep hierarchies. jQuery (find, each, closest)

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, each

i have code

```
<table id="financial101_tab1" class="dxrpControl_Moderno dxrpWithoutHeader_Moderno" style="border-collapse: separate; opacity: 1; margin-left: 0px;">

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="financial101_tab1_RPC" class="dxrp dxrpcontent" style="padding: 6px 10px 10px; border-width: medium; border-style: …r-color: -moz-use-text-color; background-color: transparent;">
            <input id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab1ATI" type="hidden" value="1" name="BlockControlfinancial101_tab1ATI"></input>
            <div id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab1" class="dxtcLite_Moderno dxtc-top" style="">
                <ul id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab1_TC" class="dxtc-strip dxtc-stripContainer" style="padding: 3px 0px 0px; width: 624px;"></ul>
                <div id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab1_CC" class="dxtc-content" style="visibility: visible; width: 600px;"></div>
                <input type="hidden" name="BlockControlfinancial101_tab1_DXState" value="{"t":[]}"></input>
            </div>
            <b class="dx-clear"></b>
            <script id="dxss_1482507144" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

there are 6 tables,

i want to get all elements by class names `.dxrpControl_Moderno.dxrpWithoutHeader_Moderno`, because they are the same in 6 t tables,  and im tying to set it's childs `#BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_AT0`background, already have

```
$(".dxrpControl_Moderno.dxrpWithoutHeader_Moderno").each(function () {
            if ($(".dxrpControl_Moderno.dxrpWithoutHeader_Moderno").find(".dxtc-text.dx-vam").text() == "Гистограмма") {
                $(".dxrpControl_Moderno.dxrpWithoutHeader_Moderno").find("#BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_AT0").css('background', 'url(../../CustomStyleSource/icons/chart_bar_icon24.png) no-repeat center center');
            }
        });
```

sadly it doesn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$(this)` to target current `.dxrpControl_Moderno.dxrpWithoutHeader_Moderno` inside each loop:

```
$(".dxrpControl_Moderno.dxrpWithoutHeader_Moderno").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find(".dxtc-text.dx-vam").text().trim() == "Гистограмма") {
        $(this).find(".BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_AT0").css('background', 'url(../../CustomStyleSource/icons/chart_bar_icon24.png) no-repeat center center');
    }
});
```

Also, `id` is unique, you should use class instead, so you need to change:

```
id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_AT0"
```

to:

```
class="BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_AT0"
```

for your elements.

Comment: Why do you need `$(this).find("#BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_AT0")` is't `$("#BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_AT0")` will be sufficent

Comment: It should be class, not id.

Comment: how i cana go deeper in hierarchy? like this <el1><e1><e>1</e></e1></el1>

Comment: @user3102504 `.find()` can take you to any level from the parent element

Comment: i used `$(".dxrpControl_Moderno.dxrpWithoutHeader_Moderno").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find(".dxtc-text.dx-vam").text() == "Гистограмма") {
alert("a");}});` it doesn't work, don know why hlp

Comment: @user3102504 Your HTML doesn't have any element with class `dxtc-text` and `dx-vam`

Comment: @user3102504 It works when I add sample element with those classes to your current HTML. Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fVLbZ/

Comment: how i can show full hierarchy? i can't write it here says too long

Comment: message box doesn't appear, just copied what you wrote, and from jsfiddle too, but ;( no change